# Help to color-alternate rows in sortable table

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using jQuery [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin.  I'm relatively new to jQuery and need help from jQuery ninjas.

My table has color-alternative rows.  I used CSS nth-child() to alternate the rows.

```
table.tablesorter tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color:#FBFBFB;
}
```

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but IE doesn't like it.  IE doesn't support nth-child.

I tried to control color-alternating with JavaScript when page loads.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#packageTbl').tablesorter();
  $('table.tablesorter tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td').css('background-color', '#FBFBFB');
  $('table.tablesorter tbody tr:nth-child(even) td').css('background-color', '#DDD');
});
```

And it works fine when the page originally loads but when I click on a column to sort, my color-alternative rows do not alternate any more.  I might have two white rows then three gray ones.

Can you suggest any solution that can help me.

Comment: Stop supporting IE is the best option ;)

Comment: @mazzzzz I wish I had this option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tablesorter has a built in function to "zebra" stripe the rows, it also automatically updates the striping after sorting. Use it as follows:

CSS

```
.NormRow { background-color: #fbfbfb; }
.AltRow  { background-color: #ddd; }
```

Script

```
$('#packageTbl').tablesorter({
   widgets: ['zebra'],
   widgetZebra: {css: ["NormRow","AltRow"]} // css classes to apply to rows
});
```

---

Update: Actually, the default CSS the tablesorter uses is "odd" and "even" so change the css names to that if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
$('.tablesorter tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass('odd');
```

CSS:

```
.odd {
    background-color:#FBFBFB;
}
```

[Example can be found here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Shaz/xrak2/).

Comment: It's basically the same what I'm trying to do.  I'll have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @Vadim: Works for me in IE7, how far back you need to go?