# Tablesorter JS Cannot implement odd/even

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

I'm trying to implement the odd even and blue theme to replicate the demo.

I have everything working:

- jquery.latest.js
- jquery.tablesorter.js
- blue theme

The only thing that doesn't work is the odd and even coloring of each row. This is my .

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js">
 </script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myTable").tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra']});

    </script>
</head>
```

I hard coded the `header` class for the headers, but I tried to write a function to set the class to odd and even, but when I sort the table, the rows mess up. Example: 3 light 1 dark 4 light 2 dark

I'm guessing it has to do with `zebra`, and I tried searching SO and the documentation but I came up empty.

Comment: Found a decent answer to how to do it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783504/help-to-color-alternate-rows-in-sortable-table

Answer (score 2):

No need to do this with classes any more. Just use CSS!

```
#myTable tr {
  background: red;
}

#myTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: blue;
}
```

This is supported by IE9+ and other major browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

Comment: Love the solution... but I really need the IE7 and 8 capability as well.